# setPrefHeight() not working within changeListener (for gridView)

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

I want the height of my [gridView](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html) to get automatically adjusted while changing its width (resizing window), the gridView scrollBar doesn't show up and I get one scrollBar (from scrollPane) for the gridView and some additional nodes together. But for some reason the `setPrefHeight()` within the changeListener has no effect.

Using `gridView.setPrefHeight(1000);` for example in the `initialize()` method of the the controller class has the desired effect.

MainApp.java

loads the FXML file and make the stage show up:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;    

import java.io.IOException;    

public class MainApp extends Application {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }    

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {    

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("View.fxml"));    

        try {    

            AnchorPane rootPane = loader.load();    

            Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 500, 300);    

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();    

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    

    }
}
```

Controller.java

The controller class in that the gridView is initialized and where the changeListener is located:

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import org.controlsfx.control.GridCell;
import org.controlsfx.control.GridView;
import org.controlsfx.control.cell.ColorGridCell;    

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;    

public class Controller implements Initializable {    



    @FXML
    private GridView<Color> myGrid;    


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {    


        ObservableList<Color> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();    

        myGrid.setCellFactory(new Callback<GridView<Color>, GridCell<Color>>() {
            public GridCell<Color> call(GridView<Color> gridView) {
                return new ColorGridCell();
            }
        });    

        Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());    

        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {    

            list.add(new Color(r.nextDouble(), r.nextDouble(), r.nextDouble(), 1.0));
        }    

        myGrid.setItems(list);    


        myGrid.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {    

                //Nothing happens
                myGrid.setPrefHeight(10000);    

            }
        });    

    }    
}
```

View.fxml

The gui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import org.controlsfx.control.GridView?>    

<AnchorPane prefHeight="118.0" prefWidth="473.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller">
   <children>
      <ScrollPane fitToWidth="true" prefHeight="174.0" prefWidth="473.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <content>
            <VBox>
               <children>
                  <AnchorPane>
                     <children>
                        <Label layoutX="63.0" layoutY="57.0" text="Some Nodes" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="63.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="57.0" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
                  <GridView fx:id="myGrid" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: What is the scene structure? Your listener is most likely called for the first time after the initial size of the `GridView` is set and the scene does not change size unless you modify the size of the window containing it.

Comment: I have a scrollPane containing a vBox. One child of the vBox is the gridView wrapped in a AnchorPane. If i put a `System.out.println();` within the changeListener i get the expected output. But the height is not changing (while changing the window width).

Comment: please provide a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem  ;)

Comment: I hope my problem gets clear now with my updated question :)